# Product of the inverse of a positive definite matrix and a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let P be a symmetric positive definite matrix and A is a symmetric matrix (with A and P real-valued matrices). Show that $P^{-1} A$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are all real.

I tried to show that $P^{-1} A$ is symmetric to apply the spectral theorem but this is not obvious if $P^{-1} A $ and $A P^{-1} $ are different. What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. $P^{-1}A$ is not necessarily symmetric. Just try some random examples.

However, it is true that $P^{-1}A$ has a real spectrum. This is because the product is similar to $P^{-1/2}AP^{-1/2}$.